# How to utilize if function to select which rows of data to consider in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm trying to create a script for Google Sheets that sends an e-mail to A*, with the subject B*, and body C*, and that writes "Sent" (or whatever else) on column D*, and checks for that column to know when to jump to the next one or not. So far I got:

```
function sendMailtest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet');
  var n=sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) 
  {
    var check = sheet.getRange(i,4);
    if (check == "Sent") {
      break;
    } else {
    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var subject = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var message = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    check.setValue("Sent");
    }
  }
}
```

It actually works perfectly for how simple it is, my only problem is that no matter what I do with the IF statement, it always completely ignores it and sends an email for each row regardless of the information in column D. I've tried using break, continue, both with and without else{} so far, without any success. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is nonsense `check.setValue("Sent");` check is not a range

Comment: Read this until you understand what the problem  is: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)

Comment: @Cooper While I was writing the answer, you also wrote about the text/range, I did not see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var check = sheet.getRange (i, 4);
```

Here check is a range, but in

```
if (check == "Sent")
```

you are comparing it to text, so the equality is never satisfied.
If you fix the code like this, then everything works well:

```
function sendMailtest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet');
  var n=sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) 
  {
    var check = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    if (check != "Sent") {
      var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
      var subject = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var message = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      //    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      Logger.log(emailAddress + ":" + subject + ":" + message);
      sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue("Sent");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer